# Daily Update Installation for Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

On the following page I see that you have posted the daily updates for the Ubuntu for Android zip file. There are the image files down below and then there is a zip file above with a .zip.md5sum. I don't want to flash the image but instead us my android recover to flash the files to install the ubuntu for android update. I know when you guys launched Ubuntu for Android the first day there were two zips files that I could flash on my phone to install it. Would it be the same process for these files? Would I have to rename the second file so it ends with .zip rather then .zip.md5sum in order to flash it? Whats the process of flashing these files? The instructions on the main page do not referenece the flashable zips so I am assuming that the page has not been updated. Thank you and look forward to your reply.

My Device: Google Nexus 4 (Mako)

quantal-preinstalled-armel+mako
quantal-preinstalled-armel+mako.zip.md5sum

Daily Update Files: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Comment: Why don't you want to go the suggested way and instead use your own way with your "android recover"? You might have to invest a little time in order to understand how the flashing process works if you want to do it your way. But let me point out that renaming a *.md5sum to *.zip will not work to achieve your goal.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu for Android available for download, can the title be changed? From the description it is referring to Ubuntu Touch.

Answer (score 1):

Just flash the same files you needed first:

1. quantall-preinstalled-armel+mako.zip
2. quantal-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip

I did this a few hours ago (with maguro) and its working perfect, running it right now. Just read the names and download the correct ones.